# javascript - change the Page source Reference File Path

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Application that has a reference to a javascript file . Long story short, For lot of Reasons, i cannot change this js file nor can i change place where it is referred. So i want to use javsacript to change the reference file path to my file .

ie:  in my application  i have a reference at the end of the page like :

```
   <script src="FileThatIsCorrupted.js"></script>
```

i cannot change the reference path of this file nor can i change the content of this file.

But i have another js file that loads at the top of the page as

```
 <script src="FileIHaveFullControl.js"></script>
```

i want to write a Snippet in my fullControl file to change the Reference path to

```
<script src="CorrectFile.js"></script>
```

I tried `document.querySelectorAll('script')`  and `document.find('script')`
But that is not helping. Need any pointers

Comment: Client side JS cannot write to files. You can alter the script source my removing the script, and creating and adding a new one with the altered src path to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can try to use the holdready function of jquery like follows

```
$.holdReady( true );
$.getScript( "myplugin.js", function() {
   $.holdReady( false );
});
```

then you must looking for the script element that contains an attribute src like "FileIHaveFullControl.js" and remove it.

```
$("script").each(function(i, j){
    if($(this).attr("src").equals("corrupted file url"))
        $(this).remove(); 
});
```

most information on the jquery reference http://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't have access to the html file and thus you can't editing it (otherwise the question would make no sense), I'm affraid I have to inform you that a script src can only be set once. It's not possible to change it.

But it turns out that you can replace from the dom instead. I found this function on the web:

```
function createjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 return fileref
}

function replacejscssfile(oldfilename, newfilename, filetype){
 var targetelement=(filetype=="js")? "script" : (filetype=="css")? "link" : "none" //determine element type to create nodelist using
 var targetattr=(filetype=="js")? "src" : (filetype=="css")? "href" : "none" //determine corresponding attribute to test for
 var allsuspects=document.getElementsByTagName(targetelement)
 for (var i=allsuspects.length; i>=0; i--){ //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
  if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr)!=null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr).indexOf(oldfilename)!=-1){
   var newelement=createjscssfile(newfilename, filetype)
   allsuspects[i].parentNode.replaceChild(newelement, allsuspects[i])
  }
 }
}

replacejscssfile("oldscript.js", "newscript.js", "js") //Replace all occurences of "oldscript.js" with "newscript.js"
replacejscssfile("oldstyle.css", "newstyle", "css") //Replace all occurences "oldstyle.css" with "newstyle.css"
```

SOURCE CODE:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml

Comment: Is there anyway, we can change the content of the Corruptedfile.js?

Comment: Not exactly. But there is a solution. Check at my answer. I edited id.

Comment: I checked this. But i am not sure if this would work because the Corrupted file has the document.ready code and that will be loaded before i remove the reference of the file  :(

Comment: In that case, there's still hope. Check at the other answer to your question. It mentions a jquery function to hold the document ready $.holdReady. You can find more info about that method in the provided link also. It basically says that you have to apply that function right after the head tag.