# Change script source to absolute path

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with software where I cannot directly edit the HTML of everything. I am pulling a form that was creating using the software into an iframe. The form references scripts using relative paths. This causes a secure content error when the form is pulled in through the iframe. Is there a way to update these src links? This is what I have tried

```
<body>
  <contentform></contentform>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
  <script>
    $('script[src*="/folder/test/test.js"]').attr('src', 'https://www.link.org/folder/test/test.js');
    $('script[src*="/folderb/test/test2.js"]').attr('src', 'https://www.link.org/folder/test/test2.js');
  </script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="/folder/test/test.js">
  <script language="JavaScript" src="/folder/test/test2.js">
</body>
```

The scripts work when I put them in console but not when I load them in the page.  is the actual form and I can place the script just below that or above it but I am not able to directly edit the location or html for

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="/folder/test/test.js">
<script language="JavaScript" src="/folder/test/test2.js">
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The script `src` can only be set once. It's not possible to change it. You can replace from the dom instead, read my answer to a similar question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27027664/4263082